# Django ManyToMany related manager with no objects returns True

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-related-manager

Django 1.9, Python 3.6, postgres DB

There exists `Calendar` and `CalendarOwner`, where the many-to-many relationship is defined in `Calendar`.

```
class Calendar(models.Model):
    ...
    calendar_owners = models.ManyToManyField(
        'some_app.CalendarOwner',
        blank=True,
        related_name='calendars',
    )
    ...
    def calendar_method(self):
        return self.calendar_owners.calendar_owner_method()


class CalendarOwner(models.Model):
    ...
    def calendar_owner_method(self):
        ...
        # returns a bool, depends on condition
```

When I am calling `Calendar.calendar_method()` for `Calendar` that has `CalendarOwner`(s) associated with it, `CalendarOwner.calendar_owner_method()` is called for each `CalendarOwner`, and works as intended - I get a boolean according to whatever logic I have in there. 
 
I think that the way it works is that from all the method calls, if there is at least one `True` the execution breaks and the return value is `True`.
 Otherwise it will call on all the related objects and finally return `False`.

The question:
Why is it that when I am calling `Calendar.calendar_method()` when no `CalendarOwner`(s) are associated with `Calendar` it never calls `CalendarOwner.calendar_owner_method()` and always returns `True`. 
Is that the default behavior?

Example:

```
>>> obj = Calendar()
<Calendar: Str>
>>> obj.calendar_owners.count()
0
>>> obj.calendar_owners.calendar_owner_method()
True
```

It makes sense that since there are no `CalendarOwner`(s) associated with that `Calendar` the `CalendarOwners.calendar_owner_method()` would not be called at all. But why does it return True? Can someone point me to the docs?

I can check if `Calendar.calendar_owners.count()` is zero and return `False`, but I want to see if there is any better Django way of doing that.

Comment: This code wouldn't give you the result you claim; `calendar_owners` is a queryset, which doesn't have a `calendar_owner_method` method, so you would just get an error. If you want help you need to show real code.

Answer (score 0):

`obj.calendar_owners` is a [Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/) and not an instance of `CalendarOwner`, so it has not `calendar_owner_method`.